# BGProcessingTask Perform Bluetooth Connection with Core Bluetooth in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bgprocessingtask

When app goes to background I wanted to connect bluetooth device with Core Bluetooth, With `BGProcessingTask`I was able to perform background task(it executes after 15 min keeping app in background) but connection is not happening it didn't trigger `CBCentralManagerDelegate`methods.

Here is what I've tried.

1. I have enabled necessary Background Modes in Capabilities.
   [image]
2. Added required things in info.plist.
   [image]
3. When app launches I'm registering BGProcessingTask as below.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.cancelAllTaskRequests()
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.myAppTest.backgroundsync", using: nil) { task in
            // Downcast the parameter to an app refresh task as this identifier is used for a refresh request.
            print("background task triggered")
            if let appRefreshTask = task as? BGProcessingTask {
                self.handleBackgroundSync(task: appRefreshTask)
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

4. When app goes to background will submit request and after 15 min it starts executing task **handleBackgroundSync** function.

```
    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        print(#function)
        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).scheduleBackgroundRefresh()
    }
```

```
    func scheduleBackgroundRefresh() {
        let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: "com.myAppTest.backgroundsync")
        //        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 1 * 60) // Fetch no earlier than 15 minutes from now
        request.requiresNetworkConnectivity = true // Need to true if your task need to network process. Defaults to false.
        request.requiresExternalPower = true
        do {
            print("App send to background")
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

5. In the **handleBackgroundSync** function as usual I'm trying to connect bluetooth device with Core Bluetooth. With breakpoint can debug upto scanning but **CBCentralManagerDelegate** delegates methods are not triggering and when I come to foreground then it triggers.

```
// Establish bluetooth Connection.
func handleBackgroundSync(task: BGProcessingTask) {
    task.expirationHandler = {
        print("Request expired")
    }
    // Here establishing bluetooth connection and once task is completed marking task as completed.
    // Connection is with Core Bluetooth as usual, but Can't share that piece of code. 
    // Wanted to know the steps to establish proper bluetooth connection. 
}
```

With the BGProcessingTask can someone please suggest a way to establish bluetooth connection.

Comment: Firstly - please post your code directly instead of screenshots. Secondly - how do you call your scheduleBackgroundRefresh method ?

Comment: As far as I know you can only reconnect to devices in background with the appropriate uuid. You can´t discover and establish new connections.

Comment: You shouldn't need to scan. You should already know the peripheral identifier you want to connect to, so use `retrievePeripherals` and then `connect`. Even then, I have my doubts about this approach. You should probably just use regular Core Bluetooth background processing to remain connected to the peripheral and then retrieve data from the already connected peripheral from your background task.

Comment: Updated question with code. I think we have to perform scan to get the availble bluetooth devices right? Can you share the steps so that I can follow and try to make it work.

Comment: Don't you want to connect to a previously discovered peripheral?  You should save the `identifier` and then you can use `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` to get the `CBPeripheral` without needing to scan.